# Error when activating a TYPO3 extension using Composer

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I am running the following command in the directory where my root composer.json file is located:

```
 ./vendor/bin/typo3 extension:activate slickcarousel
```

However, I get the following error in return:

```
In ConnectionPool.php line 110: The requested database connection named "Default" has not been configured.
```

Even though I have configured my database in my LocalConfiguration.php. I also cannot find the ConnectionPool.php file in the vendor directory. How do I fix this error?

Comment: path for `ConnectionPool` is `typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Database/ConnectionPool.php`

Comment: Thank you! I still don't get why it is not working though, since I am using the correct password and username for my database configuration...

Comment: If you made and update of TYPO3 you should execute the update-wizard first. The notation about the database in the file `typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php` differs between versions

Comment: I don't think I updated TYPO3, but nonetheless how do I execute the update-wizard?

Comment: The wizard is in the install-tool, never executed it by cli, but suppose thats possible too

Comment: did you find a solution for this? i have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a different TYPO3 Context maybe? then you need to set that as well with

`TYPO3_CONTEXT=Development ./vendor/bin/typo3 extension:activate slickcarousel`

Comment: I have not set up a TYPO3 context, so I don't think that's it but thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Side note: In Typo3 v11 and later this action has been removed.

There are only two extension:* actions now:

```
extension
   extension:list        Shows the list of extensions available to the system
   extension:setup       Set up extensions
```

For a complete list of all commands use the following command in your shell:

```
./vendor/bin/typo3
```